# How to show laptop battery not the mouse battery, when fully charged?

Tags: mouse, laptop, indicator, battery

Ubuntu 16.10.

When the laptop battery is being charged, the indicator in the top bar shows the percentage of the laptop battery (I have set it to display the percentage). The problem is that, when I the laptop is fully charged with the charger connected, it shows the wireless USB mouse battery percentage, and I could see any way to select the laptop battery instead.

If I unplug the charger, then it displays the laptop battery again. I read  similar questions and tried one of the suggested solutions. I changed the display option to [When battery is charging/in use]. But this made the icon disappear in the situation above.

Is there anyway to make Ubuntu display the laptop battery percentage *always*, whether it is being charged, in use or not, just like other operating systems such as Windows or macOS? I do not need to see mouse battery in real time as it changes really really slowly (the batteries last almost a year).

Answer (score 0):

go in to Settings (click the cog)

choose Power

ensure that 'Show battery status in the menu bar' shows anything but 'Never'

this should enable the battery status

when you see the battery indicator you can then right click to choose percentage or icon display of remaining charge.